# MySQL and SQL Server / Keyword not supported: 'data source HOST.com;initial catalog'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection

Note as of 9/16/2019 at 3:30 EDT

### I have disabled the parts of my app that use the SQL Server DB so my site would not crash. Just as info, in case anyone access my site and can't reproduce the error.

I have read most if not all of the similar threads to no avail. My site uses BOTH MySQL and SQLserver. Everything works fine on my PC [localhost]. I issued the code for the first time this weekend, and have run into this problem with the published code on my hosting site. I am able to access the MySQL DB just fine, but when I try and access the SQLServer, I get the error -- Keyword not supported: 'data source HOST.com;initial catalog'.

Web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>

        <add name='DefaultConnection' providerName='System.Data.SqlClient' connectionString='Data Source=[HOST Server];Initial Catalog=aspnet-Lat34North-20190423140228;Integrated Security=SSPI' />
        <add name='Lat34NorthContext' providerName='System.Data.SqlClient' connectionString='Data Source=[HOST Server];Initial Catalog=Lat34North;Integrated Security=False;User Id=[user id 1]; Password=[password 1]'  />
        <!--  Production -->

        <add name="CitiesContext" connectionString="Data Source=[HOST Server]; Database=Lat34CitiesSQL; uid=[user id 2]; pwd=[password 2];" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

**DAL**

```
using Lat34North.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Lat34North.DAL
{


    public class Lat34NorthContext : DbContext
    { 
            public DbSet<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
            public DbSet<MarkersPrevNext> MarkersPrevNext { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().Property(p => p.PhotoFile).HasColumnType("image");
            modelBuilder.Entity<MarkersPrevNext>().HasKey(t => new { t.StateCounty, t.Sequence });

        }

    }


}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using Lat34North.DAL;
using Lat34North.Models;


namespace Lat34North.Controllers
{
    public class HistoricMarkersALController : BaseController
    {
        private ALMarkersContext db = new ALMarkersContext();
        private Lat34NorthContext db2 = new Lat34NorthContext();

---- skip ahead  --

         int CurrentCount = CountPrevNext(PrevNextLocation, "M"); // Count number if records created today 
            if (CurrentCount == 0)
            {
                var temps = db.ALHistoricMarkers.Where(t => t.County == county_name).OrderBy(t => t.Title).ToList();
                string dateCreated = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var temp in temps)
                {
                    db2.MarkersPrevNext.Add(new MarkersPrevNext()  ***<--Error here***
                    {
                        StateCounty = PrevNextLocation,
                        Sequence = i,
                        Type = "M",  // Type M - marker
                        MarkerKey = temp.MarkerKey,
                        CraetedDate = dateCreated
                    });
                    i++;
                }
                db2.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(vModel);
        }
```

**Error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Keyword not supported: 'data source HOST.com;initial catalog'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source HOST.com;initial catalog'.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source {Server name.com];initial catalog'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +418
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +99
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +25
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +166
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +57
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +148
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +270
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +129
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +92
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +515
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +83
   Lat34North.Controllers.BaseController.DeletePrevNext(String PrevNextLocation, String type) in c:\Lat34North\Lat34North\Controllers\CommonController.cs:71
   Lat34North.Controllers.HistoricMarkersALController.SearchChurches(String option, String search) in c:\Lat34North\Lat34North\Controllers\HistoricMarkersALController.cs:459
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: try this. `<add name='Lat34NorthContext' providerName='System.Data.SqlClient' connectionString='Data Source=[HOST Server];Initial Catalog=Lat34North;Integrated Security=False;User Id=[user id 1]; Password=[password 1]  />`

Comment: missing `]` on hostname

Comment: Well, that is just a place holder and not the real host name. I have the real host name in my actual web.config, kind of like the [password 1] is not the real password, the missing ] is just a typo from when I changed the real host name to [HOST Server].

Answer (score 0):

change your config to the following. you missed a closing `'` for `connectionString=''`

```
 <add name='Lat34NorthContext' connectionString='Data Source=[HOST Server];Initial Catalog=Lat34North;Integrated Security=False;User Id=[user id 1]; Password=[password 1];Min Pool Size=20; Max Pool Size=200;' providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If your SQL Server is on one domain controller and you are trying to connect to it from another domain controller then you will get this error when `IntegratedSecurity = true;`

Integrated security means simply - use your windows credentials for login verification to SQL Server. So, if you are logged in to a different domain controller then it will fail. In the case where you are on two different domain controllers then you have no choice but to use `IntegratedSecurity = false;`

Comment: Thanks, but this was another one of those typos from when I changed the real password to [password 1]. I checked the my config and the close ' was there.

Comment: I may have to rethink this whole thing. When I tried to login the my new web site, I get "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

Comment: @user2888722 If you using windows authentication make sure that password of the user hasn't expired. An expired password can explain this error. try adding `IntegratedSecurity = false;` in above connection string

Comment: Normally my site does not require a login. It is viewable by anyone. I don;t have Integrated Security in the MySQL strings, I give that a shot.

Comment: I’ve tried both true and false, neither solves the issue. One of the blogs I read said you could not mix both MySQL and SQLServer, starting to think that maybe the case. The Membership part of the app, only uses the SQLServer DB, this generates a totally different error about an untrusted server (I think, I’ve temporarily turn that function off).

Comment: I did find an article titled “Creating ASP.NET Membership Tables in a MySQL Database” by Rei Tu and a second one titled “Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider” by Raquel Soares De Almeida, Suhas Joshi, Tom FitzMacken. It should be no big deal to convert my other functions that use SQLServer, then I would just need to get the membership part converted to MySQL. Unless someone has a solution that would allow me to mix the two.